# ValidityState problem with programatically populating a form field

Tags: javascript

I am using the ValidityState interface to provide client side form validation. I've discovered that when my form is populated progrmatically, say after a call to a 3rd party API, the tooLong state is always false, even when the field length is exceeded.

I've create a really simple mocked codepen example:

```js
document.querySelector('form').setAttribute('novalidate', true);

const input = document.getElementById("test");
input.value = "inputstringtoolonga";

console.log(input.validity);
```

```css
.field {
  max-width: 410px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
    <form class="validate" autocomplete="off">
      <div class="field">
        <input placeholder="Test" type="text" maxlength="6" class="form-control" id="test" pattern="^[0-9]+$" required>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

As can be seen if the pattern isn't matched then the patternMimatch state is correctly set to be true, but the tooLong is always false (I know the pattern used is out of context but I used it for ease and because it is simple to invalidate).

Clearly it can be seen that the maxlength attribute is exceeded by the input.

What am I missing?

Comment: According to MDN: Note: This property is never true in Gecko, because elements' values are prevented from being longer than maxlength. If true, the element matches the :invalid and :out-of-range CSS pseudo-classes. - Maybe it's got something to do with this note.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/maxlength)

> The input will fail constraint validation if the length of the text value of the field is greater than maxlength UTF-16 code units long. Constraint validation is only applied **when the value is changed by the user.**

So this constraint isn't checked when the value is assigned programmatically.

Some browsers (e.g. Chrome) actually implement `maxlength` interactively -- they won't allow you to type more characters into the input field. But this doesn't apply when assigning to the value.

You could change your `pattern` attribute to check this, since this constraint is checked even for assigned values. So change

```
pattern="^[0-9]+$"
```

to

```
pattern="[0-9]{1,6}"
```

(Note that you don't need `^` and `$` anchors, these are automatically assumed in `pattern`.)

Comment: Instead, one could use the [`pattern` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern): This constraint is checked even when the value is assigned programmatically. You could use it like this: `pattern=".{0,6}"` (for max. length of 6).